# How to change comment text using hooks

Tags: 6, comments

Under each node there is a 'Add Comment' text. For a particular content type I want to change the text to 'review by adding comment". How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.
>
> Features
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need a few easy text changes.